# adding a loading sign while the entire shiny app is loaded

Tags: r, shiny

I have developed a shiny app that is live and can be accessed [here](https://miamioh.edu/cas/academics/centers/scripps/research/ohio-population/interactive/). The problem is that it takes a few seconds for the entire app to be loaded. I was wondering if there was any way to add a loading sign such that users understand that something is coming up.

Here are a few simplified first and last lines of my code:

```
 #First lines

     ui <- fluidPage(

        navbarPage(
          collapsible = T,
          fluid = T,
          selected = "Population Projections",
          windowTitle = "Scripps Interactive Data Center",
          "",

          tabPanel(("Population Projections"),


      [the rest of the codes are here]


 server <- function(input, output) {


[the rest of the codes are here]


#last line
        shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thanks

Comment: https://waiter.john-coene.com/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loading screen and navbarPage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32310813/loading-screen-and-navbarpage)

Answer (score 1):

Use `library(shinycssloaders)` and `tableOutput(id) %>% withSpinner()`.